# Exporting large rasters in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, export, gdal-merge, large-datasets

When exporting large raster data in Google Earth Engine to your Google Drive, is there a function that prevents the export from automatically tiling into smaller files, or even decreases the number of tiles that are exported?  My maxPixels is set to 1e13.

I've also used GDAL in QGIS to merge my raster tiles but it takes ~12 hours to complete the task (I had 20 rasters of ~12 GB total, and the merged raster was 75 GB).  Any suggestions for faster processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the number of tiles you get with the `fileDimensions` argument in `Export.image.toDrive()`:

> **FileDimensions (List|Number, optional):**
>
> The dimensions in pixels of each image file, if the image is too large
>   to fit in a single file. May specify a single number to indicate a
>   square shape, or an array of two dimensions to indicate
>   (width,height). Note that the image will still be clipped to the
>   overall image dimensions. Must be a multiple of shardSize.

I normally create a VRT instead of merging my tiles together to a single file.

The speed of your export mostly depends on what you're trying to export - how much processing is required.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what is meant by shardSize?

Comment: According to the docs: "Size in pixels of the shards in which this image will be computed." My understanding is that it's the tile size Google breaks your image into, for running processing across their cluster of machines.

Answer (score 0):

Following to the Daniel respond, I can tell that you could use two parameters in `Export.image.toDrive` function that control the size and numbers of the exported files from your main image. These are `shardSize` and `fileDimensions`.

`fileDimensions` controls pixel size of each exported files. The default pixel size is 256 (which can be changed with `shardSize`) which means that your exported images will be spilt into 256 pixels tile, and saved into your drive.

In case you want to increase or decrease pixels of your exported images, you need to specify the value of `shardSize` argument. Once you define it, your `fileDimensions` can take value equal or in multiple size of your `shardSize` (below image)

[image]